# Remove white space from list output

Tags: python, list, spaces

The code I have written is to produce the fibonacci series to the point chosen by the user, for example '10' will produce:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

The problem is the empty space, I was wondering if it was possible to get it to print like this instead:

```
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
```

without the spaces.

This is the code I'm using:

```
a=int(input("write the length of numbers you would like to see the fibonacci series for(by entering 0 or 1 the output will be [1,1]):  "))

if a<0:
     print("invalid entry please type a positive number")
else:        
    i=2
    fibs=[1,1]
    b=fibs[-2]
    c=fibs[-1]
    d=b+c
    while i<a :
        i=i+1
        b=fibs[-2]
        c=fibs[-1]
        d=b+c
        fibs.append(d)
print(fibs)
```

Comment: You don't have a choice on the representation of a `list`, but you can format the output yourself.

Comment: I personally like in some cases to treat the objects as they really are, if I presice to customize https://gist.github.com/anonymous/edec7353fa8b61e66e2d

Answer (score 2):

When you print a container like that, its use of whitespace is already decided in it's `__repr__` method. You'll have to format the output yourself:

```
print('[{}].format('",".join(map(str, fibs))))  # Instead of print(fibs).
```

Comment: @user3075452 Glad I could help. Consider accepting my answer with the tick under to show that your issue is closed. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
print('[{}]'.format(','.join([str(x) for x in fibs])))
```

Creates a new list made up of your numbers converted to strings, joins it with a comma and prints it between braces.

Please note that *this is not the fastest and easiest way* to do what you want.